# Co-linear and perpendicular vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have perpendicular vectors $ \vec{a}$ and $\vec{b} $, then $\vec{a}.\vec{b} = 0$.  What happens if they are co-linear? Would you just get $\vec{a}.\vec{b} = ||\vec{a}||.||\vec{b}|| . 1 $?

Also, does $\vec{a}$ x $\vec{b} = 0$ if they're co-linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For colinear vectors you have $\vec a\cdot \vec b=\pm ||\vec a||\cdot|\vec b||$.
And, yes, you also have $\vec a\times \vec b=\vec 0$ for colinear 3D vectors.